# zend_auth cookies?

Tags: zend-framework, cookies, authentication, zend-auth

I've created a simple login system and it works so far but I want the sessions to be remembered even after the browser is closed. Does Zend have something for this? I can't seem to find it. What would be the best way to do this? With XSS in mind ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control session cookies lifetime with Zend_session options:

```
  Zend_Session::setOptions(array('remember_me_seconds' => 864000))
```

The would make session and thus login information persist for 10 days.

Comment: Two problems with that approach - first: the garbage collector needs to be modified, not to remove the session storage on the server side, second: it's vulnerable to cookie highjacking with long lifetime cookies for auth. For login cookie best practises, see: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice